# Issue trying to override mui theme in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a navbar with some list items and I want to override the style of MuiListItemText when MuiListItemButton is selected. I can override the hightlight but can't do it with the text or the icon.  I can override the ListItemText but all of them, I just want to override if 'selected' (Mui-selected).
I'm using Mui 5.2.0.
This is my approach.

```
const Theme = createTheme({
    components: {        
         MuiListItemButton: {
            styleOverrides: {
              root: {
                borderRadius: '4px',
                padding: '12px',
                '&.Mui-selected': {
                  backgroundColor: '#F2F2EA',

                  MuiListItemText: {
                    styleOverrides: {
                      secondary: {
                        color: 'red',
                             ...
```

Comment: What version of Material-UI do you use and how did you override the theme your approach?

Comment: Mui 5.2.0. I've updated the post with some info, im using createTheme and ThemeProvider

Answer (score 1):

You should define the overriding theme structure in the same depth.

```
const Theme = createTheme({
    components: {        
         MuiListItemButton: {
            styleOverrides: {
              root: {...}
            }
         },
         // it should be another component, not a nested structure
         MuiListItemText: {
            styleOverrides: {
              secondary: {
                ...
```

And you can customize an individual component by using sx prop, styled-components, or makeStyles API.

https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/

Here's an example using styled-components.

```
const CustomListItemButton = styled(ListItemButton)(() => ({
  borderRadius: '4px',
  padding: '12px',
  '&.Mui-selected': {
    backgroundColor: '#F2F2EA',
    ...
}));
```

Comment: I'm currently trying that, and I can override it but all of the ItemListsTexts, I just want to change style only if MuiListItemButton is selected (and I can do it in the button with '&.Mui-selected'. So I need to override the style only if the parent is selected. How can I do that?

Comment: @Mr_Lahey, Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

Comment: Yeah I have that imported and im passing the Theme to the ThemeProvider. As I said, the MuiListItemButton is overrided, so the ThemeProvider is working